# Opening a go file inside another go program

Tags: go

I am learning Go using "The Go Programming Language" book. First chapter introduced `os.Open` module for reading files. I tried opening a go file like below.

```
  f, err = os.Open("helloworld.go")
```

I got following error:

```
   # command-line-arguments
.\helloworld.go:6:6: main redeclared in this block
        previous declaration at .\dup2.go:10:6
```

I want to understand why go behaved as if it's trying to compile the file instead of reading like other languages ( Python, Java or C) do.

What is the correct way of opening a file?

Comment: If you `go build` - then it looks like you have multiple files with `main()` function declared in the current directory. Apparently both `dup2.go` and `helloworld.go` both have `main`

Comment: @zerkms, yes both have main and are in same directory. So the only way of reading another go file is to define them in separate package?. But why would go would try to build the file when I am trying to open it for read only.

Comment: "when I am trying to open it" --- it tries to build it when you run `go build` command.

Comment: The error happens at **compile** **time** and is totally unrelated to what you try to do. Opening files, multiplying numbers, whatever, all would have triggered that error as your program itself is malformed.

Comment: The error has absolutely nothing to do with opening a file. The problem, as stated clearly, is that "main" is re-declared.

Answer (score 5):

The error you got indicate that you have 2 `main()` function in the same package.
A package can have many files. When you have multiple `.go` files in the same directory that you run `go build` command in, the compiler will build the `main` package. In this case, it detected duplicated `main()` function hence the build failed.

What you want to do is specify which file you want to build:

```
go build helloworld.go
```

With the file specified, `go build` will only build with the file(s) you have listed.

For more information on `go build` you can refer to [Golang Documentation](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Compile_packages_and_dependencies).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will read more about go build to understand it's workings.

Answer (score 0):

Though you shouldn't do it but **technically** you **can** read a '.go' file with main() from another .go file. Your case is failing as you are building a package having multiple files defining main.

Again clarifying, it is discouraged to have multiple files with main in the same package,  and it will fail when you build the package. This is so, as there should be just one entry point (main() function) in the package.

Coming to technicality , you can read a go file from another in same package, but in this case you need to build just the file (not the whole package). Alternately you can issue go run

```
$ cat main1.go 
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
        fmt.Println("Hello")
}
$
$ cat readinfolder.go 
package main

import (
        "bufio"
        "fmt"
        "os"
)

func main() {
        filehandle, err := os.Open("main1.go")
        if err != nil {
                panic(err)
        }
        defer filehandle.Close()
        scanner := bufio.NewScanner(filehandle)
        for scanner.Scan() {
                fmt.Println(scanner.Text())
        }
}
$
$
$ go build readinfolder.go 
$ ./readinfolder 
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
        fmt.Println("Hello")
}
$
```